# math: \textstyle won't work

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I'm trying to reproduce this math thingy in LaTeX:
[image: Pascal's triangle]

What I've currently done is this:
[image: Pascal's triangle my result]

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,pointednumbers]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Deutsche Sprachunterstützung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Umlaute
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\vtwo}[2]{\left(\begin{array}{c} #1 \\ #2 \end{array}\right)}
\newcommand{\vthree}[3]{\left(\begin{array}{c} #1 \\ #2 \\ #3 \end{array}\right)}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ccc}
\vtwo{0}{0} && 1 \\
\vtwo{1}{0} \vtwo{1}{1} && 1 \hspace{5mm} 1 \\
\vtwo{2}{0} \vtwo{2}{1} \vtwo{2}{2} &=& 1 \hspace{5mm} 2 \hspace{5mm} 1 \\
\vtwo{3}{0} \vtwo{3}{1} \vtwo{3}{2} \vtwo{3}{3} && 1 \hspace{5mm} 3 \hspace{5mm} 3 \hspace{5mm} 1 \\
\dots && \dots
\end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

But my text is much bigger than in the model. I think, that's because the model was set in `\textstyle`, but when I declare my math box to use `\textstyle` as well, nothing changes:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\textstyle
\begin{array}{ccc}
\vtwo{0}{0} && 1 \\
```

or

```
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ccc}
\textstyle\vtwo{0}{0} && 1 \\
```

look all the same.

What's the reason for this behavior? Why does `\textstyle` not work? Any ideas are greatly appreciated ;)

Comment: The `array` is always set in `\textstyle` so adding it again makes no difference.

Comment: you might be better using `smallmatrix` from `amsmath` package

Comment: Why not `\binom{5}{3}` from `amsmath` for example ??? That's the command designed to typeset binomial coefficients (which is the case here apparently, reproducing Pascal's triangle)

Comment: Isn't there also a tbinom forcing a small size?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If the array is already set in `\textstyle`, and `\textstyle` obviously doesn't do the trick, what style is used in the model?

Comment: @LukeLR not sure what you mean by model here? `\binom` uses the same settings as fractions so if the current style is textstyle the top and bottom are set scriptstyle

Comment: @DavidCarlisle By 'model' I meant the example I'm trying to reproduce. So it's `\scriptstyle` that makes the numbers (binoms, arrays, whatever) smaller.

Comment: @LukeLR well the numbers are set scriptstyle, although you don't normally specify that explicitly just as you normally do `x^{2}` not `x^{\scriptstyle 2}`

Comment: @DavicCarlisle Thank you, that's all I needed to know ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution with `\binom` (wrapped in `\vtwo`), but I am not happy with the `\hspace` commands right now.

I also increased the vertical stretching a little bit (`\arraystretch`)

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Deutsche Sprachunterstützung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Umlaute
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\vtwo}[2]{\binom{#1}{#2}}%left(\begin{array}{c} #1 \\ #2 \end{array}\right)}
%\newcommand{\vthree}[3]{\left(\begin{array}{c} #1 \\ #2 \\ #3 \end{array}\right)}

\newcommand{\myspace}{6mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{ccc}
\vtwo{0}{0} && 1 \\
\vtwo{1}{0} \vtwo{1}{1} && 1 \hspace{\myspace} 1 \\
\vtwo{2}{0} \vtwo{2}{1} \vtwo{2}{2} &=& 1 \hspace{\myspace} 2 \hspace{\myspace} 1 \\
\vtwo{3}{0} \vtwo{3}{1} \vtwo{3}{2} \vtwo{3}{3} && 1 \hspace{\myspace} 3 \hspace{\myspace} 3 \hspace{\myspace} 1 \\
\dots && \dots
\end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, using `\binom` really does the trick. If you dislike the use of `\hspace` for this purpose, what could be a better solution?

Comment: @LukeLR: I don't have a better way right now than to use `\hspace` ;-) Perhaps using all in an `alignat` environment, but that's another alignment again

Comment: Okay, I'll tell you if I find something ;) (But I don't believe so)

Answer (score 3):

See if the `\binom` from `asmath` gives desired result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,pointednumbers]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Deutsche Sprachunterstützung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Umlaute
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\vtwo}[2]{\;\binom{#1}{#2}\;} 

    \begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%1.2
\begin{array}{ccc}
\vtwo{0}{0} && 1 \\
\vtwo{1}{0} \vtwo{1}{1} && 1 \hspace{5mm} 1 \\
\vtwo{2}{0} \vtwo{2}{1} \vtwo{2}{2} &=& 1 \hspace{5mm} 2 \hspace{5mm} 1 \\
\vtwo{3}{0} \vtwo{3}{1} \vtwo{3}{2} \vtwo{3}{3} && 1 \hspace{5mm} 3 \hspace{5mm} 3     \dots && \dots
\end{array}
\end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

**Edit:** After then, when submit the first version of answer,, I recognize, that it is the same as Christian Hupfer answer. Now I slightly modify it.

Comment: Glad you undeleted!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I have mess with access to SE again. The image upload take to long time. Meanwhile I see, that the first version (I prepare two), is the same as your. Now I upload second version, slightly modified, however, essentially still equivalent to yours. So I anounce in my answer, that I will delete my answer ... after your kind comment I'm confused, what to do ..

Comment: Now, you made a different solution: You added `\;` before and after the `\binom` command ;-) (Keep it)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thank you for encouraging me to keep my answer alive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, `\binom` was the right idea. I'll accept @ChristianHupfer's answer, since he was first and fair in encouraging you to keep your question, but your answer is equally good. What does the `\;` thingy do you added before and after the `\binom`-command?

Comment: You're missing a `\hspace{5mm} 1 \\ ` before the `\dots`

Comment: @EthanAlvaree, it may be, this is so old answer that I don't  remember what was problem. Later I will read a question and check the answer again.